# Python выдаёт ошибку при печати русскими буквами

Tags: python, utf-8

Если в коде напечатать русские буквы, к примеру:

```
print("Периметр квадрата равен")
```

то при вызове, в консоле Python выводит

> File "c:\users\lord0\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 1
>   SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte
>   Press any key to continue . . .

Без использования русских букв всё нормально. Все это в Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Вы свой код сохранили не в кодировке utf-8

Comment: я его только напечатал.... я вообще не сохранял его

Comment: Хм, а кто тогда сохранил файл `PythonApplication1.py`, если не вы?

Comment: ну, скорее всего вижуал студия

Comment: Вот объясните как-нибудь студии, что файлы должны быть в кодировке utf-8

Comment: Вы уже читали [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Последние версии питона по умолчанию поддерживают кодировку UTF-8. Если речь идёт о Visual Studio, то рискну предположить, что она сохраняет файл с кириллицей в кодировке windows-1251.
Попробуйте в самом начале кода указать строку

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
```

Answer (score 0):

Перезапустил проект, ВС2015 выдало сообщение что все нечитаемые знаки были заменены на символы UNICODE, после просто удалил все символы-ромбы с вопросительным знаком, и напечатал русскими буквами... Всё заработало
http://prntscr.com/l6fns8 - скрин